# Get text from XPath located Element using Selenium WebDriver with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find an element using xpath and get the elements text value.

For example, I can find the element using xpath in the following way

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div/span));
```

But I want to get the text of this particular element by using JavaScript.

HTML content is like below

```
<div><span>Inner Text</span></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function you want is `getText()`.

```
String text = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div/span")).getText();
```

Comment: This is Java. I want to do it using `nodejs/javascript`

Comment: @MarkAmery The functions are usually similarly named across languages

Comment: Answer in Java coding language instead of Javascript

Answer (score 4):

```
const By = webdriver.By;

driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div/span'))
    .then(span => span.getText())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
```

Most of the actions in the webdriver for node/'javascript' return a promise, you have to do a .then to actually get the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver;
String getText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath")).getText();
```

This will return the text within that element.

Answer (score -2):

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).getText();

console.log(element);
```

Not tested, but this will do.