# getText() does not give text in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

```html
<ul id="name" class="abc">
  <li class="def">
     <a class="ghi">
       <i style="background-color: transparent;">Welcome {{username}} </i>
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Selenium IDE:

```
storeText         //ul[@id="name"]/li/a/i       a
echo              ${a}
```

The text "Welcome {{username}}" is displayed correctly.

However, in Selenium WebDriver, I am not able to get the text.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='name']/li/a/i")).getText();
```

The above line of code returns an empty value.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637032/get-text-from-xpath-located-element-using-selenium-webdriver-with-javascript

Comment: WebElement.getText() does not work for me. I am using Chrome browser. However I can get the text using Selenium IDE in Firefox browser.

Comment: Share `Html` not an `image`.

Comment: try `/ul[@id='name']/li/a/i` instead of `//ul[@id='name']/li/a/i` and see.

Comment: @SuchitKumar, Unable to locate element

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Answer (score 3):

Just identify your element and simply use `getAttribute("value");`. Store it in a string variable and print that variable.

Code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='password_2']"));
String str = element.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("value:" + str);
```

It worked for me

`getAttribute("value")`.

Always try to pass the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get the text using any locators (here I am using XPath) and set it as a string for later use. The code below will store the text contained within the XPath.

```
String nameOfStringGoesHere;
nameOfStringGoesHere=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id="name"]/li/a/i ")).getText();`
```

To assert against the stored text later on in your script:

```
Assert.assertTrue("What you want your error message to appear as...!", nameOfStringGoesHere.contains("What you want to assert"));
```

In this example, it will get the text stored within the XPath expression, and check to see if the value is "What you want to assert", if it isn't, then it will throw the error message of "What you want your error message to appear as...!"

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same symptom in different, but similar use cases. To me, the way proposed in the question is the correct one. But indeed it returns an empty string when using the Google Chrome webdriver and the correct result with the gecko webdriver. It seems more like a bug in the Chrome webdriver(?).

(My versions: Chrome driver: 2.42. Gecko driver: 0.21)